# How to avoid db.update fails if you choose a name that already exists in the table?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

The app has:

- ListView listing player names from a DB table (only one column, so it is primary key)
- EditText to write the new name
- Button to update the name of player in the list

*there are more things, but i don´t want to make it more messy

I can click a name from the list and write a new name in the EditText. When you press the button that name is updated in the list.

Everything works correctly, but there is a problem. When I write a name that it is already in the list the app fails because primary keys cannot be repeated.

Is there some way to say "if EditText text already exists in the DB... then show a toast"

I already tried "if result of db.update is -1...then show a toast", but it doesn´t work.

This is the method in MainActivity:

```
public void modificarJugador(){
        btnModificarJugador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(jugadorEliminar.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No hay ningún jugador seleccionado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    if(!etJugador.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        String jugadorModificado = etJugador.getText().toString();
                        int res = d.modificarJugador(jugadorEliminar, jugadorModificado);
                        if (res != -1) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Jugador modificado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            botonesInicio();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No se ha podido modificar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        jugadorEliminar = "";
                        etJugador.setText("");
                        listarDatos();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Escriba el nuevo nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

And this is the method in "DAOHelper" class:

```
public int modificarJugador(String jugadorEliminar, String jugadorModificado){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("NOM_JUG",jugadorModificado);

        int res = db.update(MI_TABLA,cv,"NOM_JUG=?",new String[]{(jugadorEliminar)});
        db.close();
        return res;
    }
```

And this is the logcat:

```
2021-06-10 08:58:49.243 12019-12019/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-06-10 08:58:49.285 12019-12019/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-06-10 08:58:49.544 12019-12019/? I/JDWP: type=1400 audit(0.0:12463): avc: denied { read write } for path="socket:[77425]" dev="sockfs" ino=77425 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
2021-06-10 08:58:52.938 12019-12033/? W/art: Long monitor contention with owner main (12019) at java.lang.String java.util.Locale.getScript()(Locale.java:1074) waiters=0 in void android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.updatePendingConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration) for 1.037s
2021-06-10 08:58:53.426 12019-12019/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2-1/lib/x86
2021-06-10 08:58:57.133 12019-12019/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2021-06-10 08:58:58.825 12019-12051/? D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2021-06-10 08:58:58.820 12019-12019/? I/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:12597): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=8271 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=1
2021-06-10 08:58:58.842 12019-12051/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
2021-06-10 08:58:58.853 12019-12051/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2021-06-10 08:58:58.867 12019-12051/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2021-06-10 08:58:58.881 12019-12051/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2021-06-10 08:58:58.945 12019-12051/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-06-10 08:58:58.945 12019-12051/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2021-06-10 08:58:58.946 12019-12051/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2021-06-10 08:58:58.946 12019-12051/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2021-06-10 08:58:58.964 12019-12051/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf4f852a0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
2021-06-10 09:11:17.674 12019-12026/? I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
2021-06-10 09:20:00.370 12019-12026/? I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
2021-06-10 09:20:00.605 12019-12026/? I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
2021-06-10 09:20:00.816 12019-12026/? I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
2021-06-10 09:26:29.838 12019-12026/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
2021-06-10 09:26:29.840 12019-12026/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
2021-06-10 10:19:23.807 12019-12024/? I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=25KB, data=29KB
2021-06-10 10:19:23.815 12019-12024/? I/art: After code cache collection, code=25KB, data=29KB
2021-06-10 10:19:23.816 12019-12024/? I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2021-06-10 10:19:39.805 12019-12019/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-10 10:19:39.810 12019-12019/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2, PID: 12019
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: JUGADORES.NOM_JUG (code 1555)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:734)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1577)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1523)
        at com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2.DAOHelper.modificarJugador(DAOHelper.java:54)
        at com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:95)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22262)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
2021-06-10 10:19:48.307 12019-12030/com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 80.269ms
```

Thanks in advance for any hint to solve it.

Comment: When the method `update()` does not update any row it returns 0 and not -1.

Comment: You should check wheter that name is in the list or not. You can do this easily by getting shown data in the list but also you can make a database request to see if the user is already in database before update.

Comment: @forpas You are completely right. My mistake. Thanks a lot for your help. Changing that and following MikeT explanation I have solved the problem

Comment: @AhmetKorkmaz Thanks a lot for your answer, it is a good way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues**

You have a UNIQUE index on the NUM_JUG column *(perhaps implicit if NON_JUG is defined with PRIMARY KEY)* and you are using the standard update method which uses the default **conflict action of ABORT** and therefore fails if an attempt is made to duplicate a NOM_JUG value.

As secondary issue is that the SQLiteDatabase `update` method returns the number of updates (see extract and link below) *(same for `updateWithOnConflict`)*. The number returned will never be -1 it will be 0 or more (0 indicating that no updates have been applied).

As per [SQLite Database - Update](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D))

> **Returns**
>
> int   the number of rows affected

**Fix**

To fix the main issue you should use the [**`updateWithOnConflict`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#updateWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int)) method. This takes a 4th parameter a conflict and you probably want IGNORE so you could use :-

```
int res = db.updateWithOnConflict(MI_TABLA,cv,"NOM_JUG=?",new String[]{(jugadorEliminar)},SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

So when the UNIQUE conflict occurs the update  will be ignored.

To fix the secondary issue you could use :-

```
    if (res > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Jugador modificado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        botonesInicio();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No se ha podido modificar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Great answer!! Very complete and incredibly useful. The problem has been solved and I have improved my knowledge. Thanks a lot!